# jQuery Accordion - Scroll to element with specific class on section open

Tags: jquery, scrollto, jquery-ui-accordion

I have combined a search function with a jQueryUI accordion.
 The search function highlights the title of every section that the inputted search term is found.  I am trying to figure out a way to have the **viewport** scroll to the first occurrence of a found term when a section is opened, saving the user having to scroll through potentially very long content.
  Each highlighted term is wrapped in `<span class="highlight"&gt;term&lt;/span>`.  I have got to the point where I've added an `onclick="jumpTo(chapter_number)"` handler to each section header when a term is found within it.  I just need help with the `jumpTo` function.  Thank you!

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jameshuckabonetech/YsdDn/

P.S. Fiddle is great!  First one ...

**UPDATE** Finished working code ...

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion(
{
    autoHeight: false, collapsible: true, active: false,
    activate:function(event, ui )
    {
        if ($(ui.newPanel).find('.highlight').length>0 && $("#jump-box").prop('checked') == true)
            $('html, body').animate(
            {
                scrollTop: $(ui.newPanel).find('.highlight').offset().top
            }
            , 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're going to need to add a bit more code for us to work with. A jsfiddle.net example of where you are right now is very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use onclick use the accordion's activate event.

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    autoHeight: false, collapsible: true, active: false,
    activate:function(event, ui ){
       if ($(ui.newPanel).find('.highlight').length>0)
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(ui.newPanel).find('.highlight').offset().top
              }, 2000);
    },
    beforeActivate:function(e,ui)
    {
        //if statement to check if you want to stop the accordion from opening
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Used the scrolling code from [jQuery scroll to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element#answer-6677069)

Comment: thank you, that worked (when I update jqueryui to 1.9.2 [had 1.8.2]).  However, how do I cancel the function onclick of something?

Comment: i get an error $(...).find(...).offset(...) is undefined --- any ideas?

Comment: It works on the fiddle you provided.  Something isn't named the same.  Most likely the `highlight` class. Or the panel doesn't have any highlighted items.
Step through part of the statement using a javascript debugger to find the missing part.
Edited to fix errors when there is no highlighted items.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you again.  I was using a messy pile of if statements that this totally alleviates. I just want to clarify one thing: by "cancel the function" I meant "turn off the scrolling if a radio box gets unchecked".  Edited question to include working example above ...